# Is $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(\frac z{1+z})^n$ holomorphic on the right half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Since $\sum^k_{n=0}(\frac z{1+z})^n$ is holomorphic for every $k$ in the right half plane, it suffices to show that the series is uniformly convergent in every compact subset of right half plane. But how do we show this?

Comment: Show that $|z| \leq M$ and $\Re z >0$ implies that $|\frac z {1+z}| \leq r$ for any $r \in (\frac M {\sqrt {1+M^{2}}},1)$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't quite see how this proves the uniform convergence. How do you get $(\frac{M}{\sqrt{1+M^2}},1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n$ converges to $(1-w)^{-1}$ for $|w|<1$ and diverges otherwise.

So $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z}{1+z})^n=(1-\frac{z}{1+z})^{-1}=1+z$ for $|\frac{z}{1+z}|<1$ and diverges otherwise. Of course, $1+z$ is holomorphic, so this series is holomorphic everywhere it exists (where $|\frac{z}{1+z}|<1$).

Note $|\frac{z}{1+z}|<1 \iff |z|^2<|1+z|^2$ and $|1+z|^2=1+2\mathrm{Re}(z)+|z|^2$; can you simplifty?

Comment: This is not good enough.  You need uniform convergence on compact sets to prove that the infinite sum is holomorphic.

Comment: You are right but OP may not see the completion of the argument You can add that the series is actually a  convergent geometric series and its sum is exactly $1+z$.

Comment: +1 from me. The answer is now very clear.